# Access each pod in eks with nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to implement an environment where I have the nginx ingress controller and a nginx reverse proxy on top of it.

I want to access my pods in two ways when we get an initial request we need to forward it to the service.

When a request for a specific instance or pod is made using the path I need to send the request to specific pod which managed it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to use the **Nginx** ingress and have a cookie option you can use the sticky session my can resolve your issue.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "hello-cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
spec:
```

By this way, sticky sessions, every user communicates with the same POD.

Read more at : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/

Good article for ref : https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/sticky-sessions-in-kubernetes-56eb0e8f257d

Comment: This is completely different from my question in my case the session should individually established to each pod from outside with consistent path or subdomain.